# wp_logout_url isn't forwarding to correct link

Tags: multisite, logout

I set my site up at ***parentsite.com/childsite***. When the site was there my logout button worked correctly and logged the users out and brought them back to the homepage. Here's what the code was:

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

Then I bought a new domain name (***childsite.com***) for the site and set up the A name to point to ***parentsite.com/childsite***. Now the logout button logs users out but instead of bringing them to the homepage it brings them to the homepage of ***parentsite.com***. I changed the above code to:

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('http://childsite.com') ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

but that didn't help. I've also tried

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('http://parentsite.com/childsite') ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

and

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

Any ideas? This is very frustrating and embarrassing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you pointing entirely unrelated (from WordPress point of view) domain to WP site.

When WP processes logout the redirect is performed by [`wp_safe_redirect()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_safe_redirect/), which disallows to redirect user "outside" the site. Since it has no clue about your custom domain that link is simply discarded.

I would advise to properly set up your new domain for the site, otherwise you will keep having issues from it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by

*"properly set up your new domain for the site"*?

Comment: @user36789 I mean that WP is properly migrated to it and it is setup as WP/site address in Settings > General

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but unfortunately, I don't understand it :-(. I'm using a multisite along with a plugin called "WordPress MU Domain Mapping". I looked in my Settings > General and there's no mention of a site address there.

Comment: @user36789 sorry, hadn't used multisite with custom domains. You might want to ask new question about properly changing domain in such scenario

Comment: Can I just edit the existing question or would it be best to ask a new one? (Sorry I'm new here.) Thnx!

Comment: @user36789 I think new one would be better in this specific case since this one deals more with details of redirect on logout and that issue might happen for different reasons