# Logout issue with new Domain on WP Multisite

Tags: multisite, logout

I'm using a multisite and I set my site up at ***parentsite.com/mysite***. When the logout button was clicked it worked correctly and logged the users out and brought them back to the homepage. Here's what the code was:

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

Then I bought a new domain name (***mysite.com***) for the site, installed the "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" plugin and set up the A name to point to ***parentsite.com/mysite***. Everything works fine except now the logout button brings them to the homepage of ***parentsite.com*** with this in the url: http://parentsite.com/?dm=cd427564d8195660acb35d2669c96069&action=logout&blogid=8&k=87e709a6777fa366cd42edc1c52f1db9&t=1751394297 
instead of the homepage of ***mysite.com***.

I've tried changing the above code to:

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('http://mysite.com') ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

but that didn't help. I've also tried

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('http://parentsite.com/mysite') ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

and

```
<a class="logout with-icon" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" data-icon="&#xf08b;"><?php _e('Log out', 'franklin') ?></a>
```

Any ideas? This is very frustrating and embarrassing.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any plugins and/or theme functions running that might intervene? What about some jQuery _abduction_ of that link (e.g., `$('a.logout').click(...`)?

Comment: Please make your question about need to properly configure domain, the issue with logout [was answered in your previous question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113993/wp-logout-url-isnt-forwarding-to-correct-link) and those details are irrelevant to that.

Comment: @Rarst I hear what you're saying but I'm not sure what indicates that it's set up incorrectly. It's working fine for everything else except the logout. When you visit ***mysite.com*** you see ***mysite.com*** in the url area and the page that is shown is ***parentsite.com/mysite*** which is exactly what it should be. All forms submit correctly as well.

Comment: Please, move the solution to an Answer in the appropriate box bellow, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked on the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin support page and it turns out it was a setting in the plugin that needed to be turned off. I turned off

> Redirect administration pages to site's original domain

and it's working now.

Thanks for your ideas and help!